# Upgrading from Jersey 1.* to Jersey 2.5

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey-2.0

I have decided to move to `Jersey 2.5` and I am facing certain issues in `Java Beans` conversion to `JSON`. I have a `User` Bean and from one service I am trying to return a list of `users`.

My service code which fetches the list of users:

```
@GET
@Path("getAllUsers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    //Fetching users list here
    return users;
}
```

I get following exception of server console:

```
[org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<com.example.User>.] with root cause
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<com.example.User>.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:574)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:262)
```

Am I missing any dependencies or any 2.5 specific configuration?

Comment: Nope. Which JSON provider do you use? Are you running on GF4 or are you using other container?

Comment: @MichalGajdos Jackson and Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, to make this clear. You have dependency on `jersey-media-json-jackson` or directly on Jackson 2.x and no other JSON provider (i.e. `jersey-media-moxy`). Am I right?

Comment: Actually I already had Jackson 1.9.2 and along with that I added jersey-media-json-processing-2.5.1.

Comment: Make sure you have `jersey-media-json-jackson` in your dependency list and that you're registering [JacksonFeature](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) in your app.

Comment: Thanks I'll try adding `jersey-media-json-jackson` but the link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using Jackson 1.9.x to (un)marshall JSON, make sure you have `jersey-media-json-jackson` module in your dependency list and that you're registering [JacksonFeature](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) in your application, i.e.:

```
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyResourceConfig() {
        // ... other registrations ...

        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

To see more ways how to register providers in Jersey 2 refer to this [article](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/).